# Keep the uniqueness on combination of multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a question for basic sql setting
For example

table

```
id lastname firstname
1  water    bob   
2  zet      ken
3  tem      nick
4  tem      ken
5  zet      nick
```

I dont need to set unique key on each columns though,
I want to keep uniquenss on two columns combination

for example

```
6 water nick  // is OK
```

but

```
6 zet nick  // should be banned(it is identical to row5)
```

Is there any way to set this conditions on Mysql?

Comment: A [uniqueness constraint](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/constraint-primary-key.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`add unique index(lastname, firstname)`

It's called a composite unique key.

Comment: THank you I undesrstood and made it to use this in dotorine.

Answer (score 0):

create another key (Unique index or unique constraint) on combination of firstName, lastname.  This is called a natural key, as opposed to the id column you have which is called a surrogate key.